# Web Scraping through R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I have an excel file that contains certain keywords that need to be searched in google through R.
The output to be created is a data frame which contains the following variables:

Keyword;Position(position of the url in the search results);Title(title of the ith search result);Text(text in that search result);URL;Domain
The keywords and some example of the output are given in the link below:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AM3d5Hbf5nBpbRG1ydnZM7ZG2AdUyy-6/view?usp=sharing

(Sheet 1 has the keywords and sheet 2 has the sample output)

I tried to create a similar output but there seems to be an error.
Code:

```
# Web Scraping in R
library(XML)
library(RCurl)
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
library(urltools)
library(htm2txt)
library(readxl)

data <- read_excel(file.choose()) # Importing the data
output <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=6,nrow=0))
colnames(output) <- c("Name","Position","Title","Text","URL","Domain")

for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
  search.term <- data[i,1]
  getGoogleURL <- function(search.term, domain = '.com', quotes=TRUE) 
  {
    search.term <- gsub(' ', '%20', search.term) # Cleaning the Search Term
    if(quotes) search.term <- paste('%22', search.term, '%22', sep='') 
    getGoogleURL <- paste('http://www.google', domain, '/search?q=',
                          search.term, sep='')
  }
  quotes <- "False"
  search.url <- getGoogleURL(search.term=search.term, quotes=quotes)
  page <-  read_html(search.url)
  links <- page %>% html_nodes("a") %>% html_attr("href")
  link <- links[startsWith(links, "/url?q=")]
  link <- sub("^/url\\?q\\=(.*?)\\&sa.*$","\\1", link)
  for (j in 1:length(link)) {
    page1 <- read_html(link[j])
    name <- data[i,1]
    position <- j
    title <- page1 %>% html_node("title") %>% html_text()
    text <- gettxt(link[j])
    url <- link[j]
    domain <- suffix_extract(domain(link[j]))$host
    vect <- c(name,position,title,text,url,domain)
    output <- rbind(output,vect)
    }
  
}
```

The error being shown is:

```
Error in match.names(clabs, nmi) : names do not match previous names
```

Please help, I'm new to R.

Comment: That error is typically from `rbind`, meaning that the column names don't match up. This could be because there are additional or missing columns. Since iteratively adding to a frame is bad anyway, I suggest you append each iteration's output to a `list`, then at the end use `data.table::rbindlist` or `dplyr::bind_rows` instead of `rbind`.

Answer (score 1):

That error comes from `rbind` when the columns don't line up perfectly. For instance, if there is a missing or extra column. In this case, it might be because one of your `vect` variables is empty/`NULL` or length over 1.

```r
rbind(data.frame(a=1,b=2), data.frame(b=3))
# Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : 
#   numbers of columns of arguments do not match
```

Since iteratively adding rows to a frame gets expensive (it makes a complete copy of the frame every time even one row is added, this is grossly inefficient), it's generally better to append to a `list` and convert into a frame in one call.

```t
out <- list()
for (i in seq_len(nrow(data))) {
  # ...
  for (j in seq_along(link)) {
    # ...
    vect <- c(name, position, title, text, url, domain)
    stopifnot(length(vect) == 6L)
    out <- c(out, list(vect))
  }
}
outout <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, out)
colnames(output) <- c("Name", "Position", "Title", "Text", "URL", "Domain")
```

(In reality, instead of `stopifnot`, one might record the url and data retrieved into a different `list` for forensic purposes. Or find the missing element and `NA` it before adding to the list. Either way, `stopifnot` is intended here as a placeholder for something more contextually relevant to you and your process.)